# Crystal Report printing issue on Business Objects

Tags: printing, crystal-reports, business-objects

One of our users started to have printing issue after the computer upgrade (we have changed all the computers). When he clicks on the Print button on the top left of the crystal report via BI Launchpad, it showed up error message below. If the user clicks Retry, similar error message popped up with the same wording except replacing 'LCIDTable.xml' with things like 'us10_1_422.dll.', 'csprintdlg.dll', 'PrintControl.dll', '10_1_422.dll', 'xerces-c_2_7.dll', 'pvlocale-1-0.dll'.

[image]

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error messages that you reported, it seems that the ActiveX Print Control isn't installed (properly). If an installation was attempted, it most likely failed due to the user not having sufficient rights on the OS (i.e. administrative rights).

Have a look at these SAP KB articles for more info (requires an S-ID from SAP Support):

- [1874481](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1874481) - What is the minimum required set of files to be copied on client machines which will allow users to print a report?
- [1720909](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1720909) - How to install Crystal Reports ActiveX controls (Viewing and Printing) on a end-user PC for Business Intelligence 4.0 SP2 installations
- [1641815](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1641815) - How to create Activexviewer.exe and install manually or by SMS tool in SAP BOE XI 4.0 for Windows Server

**Remark**: some notes seem to link to SAP KB [1641815](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1641815). However, as you appear to be running BI4, these instructions no longer apply.

Comment: Thanks Kristof. I do not have S-ID to access the articles. I tried to check the Business Objects Launchpad and Crystal reports About section but could not find the customer id or installation id which is required to obtain the S-ID, is there any chance you know where I can find the customer id or installation id on my SAP products?

Comment: @Jennifer an S-ID is part of your support contract. If you have an active (thus paying) support contract, you are sent an S-ID (an account). This account will be the administrator account that can create additional S-IDs for other users. Then again, you could always Google for "SAP note xxx" (xxx being the note you need) and you'd probably find the same content elsewhere, without restrictions ;-)

Comment: Thanks Dristof. I will ask our IT administrator and also try to google the articles.